# Primeng expandable column headers don't show

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have an expandable row in Angular2 using Primeng2 but the column headers for the expandable columns aren't showing.

This is my table with the expandable rows:

```
   <p-dataTable [value]="activetrucks" expandableRows="true" [(selection)]="selectedtruck">
  <p-header>
    List of Active trucks

  </p-header>
  <p-column expander="true"></p-column>
  <p-column field="owner_id" header="Transporter"></p-column>
  <p-column field="reg_no" header="Truck number"></p-column>
  <p-column field="truck_category" header="Truck type" ></p-column>

  <template let-user pTemplate="rowexpansion">  //headers dont show
    <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid"> 
      <p-dataTable [value]="stages" [paginator]="true" [pageLinks]="3">
        <p-header>
          The different stages
        </p-header>
        <p-column field="status" header="Status"></p-column>  
        <p-column field="created_at" header="Done by"></p-column>
        <p-column field="created_by" header="Date"></p-column>

        <p-column styleClass="col-button">
          <template let-truck="rowData" pTemplate="body">
            <button type="button" pButton (click)="onremoveTruck(truck)" icon="fa-remove"></button>
          </template>
        </p-column>

      </p-dataTable>
    </div>
  </template>

</p-dataTable>
```

In the expand row the headers dont show as shown in picture below.

[image]

What could be wrong?

Comment: Can you check in the developer tools whether the header texts are there but hidden by CSS or the text are not there at all?

Comment: The header texts are there but hidden by the css classes .ui-datatable-reflow .ui-datatable-data td .ui-column-title {
    display: none;
}

Comment: So probably just mark your nested table with some class and create a CSS rule that will change the display property of its headers.

Answer (score 1):

Create or edit a css file with this content:

```
th .ui-column-title {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

And edit your component file:

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
  styleUrls: ['file.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and was able to resolve it by removing the [responsive] property from the table definition.

[I have posted an answer here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2090)

Answer (score 0):

Solving the problem in 2022

```
"@angular/core": "~13.2.0",
"primeng": "^13.1.0",
```

Just add to your `p-table` prop `responsiveLayout="scroll"`:

```
<p-table responsiveLayout="scroll">
```

As I understand it, this is to override the default `responsive` behavior and the table will be normal.